# Why resourcePool agents are not accessible from this block?

Tags: anylogic, agent

I have a resourcePool block. The resource units are Worker type.

However, I cant't access this units calling the resourcePool block from conveyor Stations nor from Service blocks. No matter if I use "agent" or "unit" (in Station -> Resource choice condition), I only can access to `resourcePool.agents()`, which is a list from which I can't access to Worker agent.

Does anyone knows why, and how could I access to Worker agents considering they are created as Resource Units?

Answer (score 1):

You use agent populations for this. Create an empty population of Worker agents and set the Resource Pool (in its Advanced properties) to add units to a custom population (and select your population).

Now all the resource units are accessible via the population.